# SQL Server: Look up person records where one entry exists but missing another

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pull data from our table to show each person record that includes one service item, but excludes another.  I'd like all 'person_id' records where there is a service item of 66984 but no service item for 92136 attached.  For each person_id, there are multiple entries for each attached service item.  Here is my code I'm trying, but it comes up blank:

```
select person_id, service_item_id from charges
where exists (SELECT person_id from charges where service_item_id = '66984') 
and not exists (SELECT person_id from charges where service_item_id = '92136')
order by person_id
```

Going a step further, I'd like it to check for multiple codes at once.  So it's checking if either 92136 or 76519 do not exist and returning all person_ids that have 66984 but neither of the other codes

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, you need to add the person_id in the sub queries

```
select person_id, service_item_id from charges  
where exists (SELECT person_id from charges c1 where charges.person_id = c1.person_id and service_item_id = '66984') 
and not exists (SELECT person_id from charges c2 where charges.person_id = c2.person_id and service_item_id = '92136')
order by person_id
```